# Gamma distribution

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions

I was trying to help a friend solve this and I am really troubled.
The task was to show that $$\int_0^1x^t(1-x)^{s-t}dx=\frac{t!(s-t)!}{(s+1)!}$$ using the Gamma distribution properties.

What I did was initially to try and show that is $$\frac{t!(s-t)!}{(s+1)!}$$ this times the cumulative fuction of a Gamma multiplying/dividing the right things. What I could not think of is how to appear the exponential that I need in order to create the cumulative.

Am I wrong? How can I prove this? Also Gamma integrates from zero to infinity and in this case $$x\in (0,1)$$.

I am trying to use the formula: $$\text{Gamma}(\alpha,\lambda)\implies\frac{{\lambda}^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\cdot x^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda x}$$

Comment: The Beta and Gamma functions satisfy the relationship $$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

Comment: Thank you, I did not know it. Very interesting. However, I am looking for an elementary way of proving this, probably without using this formula.

Comment: @Chenmath There are two different Gamma distribution parametrizations. What is the PDF of the Gamma distribution you are taught in your class?

Comment: Do you know the beta distribution?

Comment: I also wonder about the Beta distribution. It would be much more useful in this case.

Comment: @Clarinetist: I edited my question with the formula I know.

Comment: The $a - 1$ on the exponent of the $x$ should be $\alpha - 1$.

Comment: @Clarinetist: I do not see the difference, is there a typo?

Comment: Yes, "a" instead of alpha.

Comment: I still think you mean gamma function. The gamma density doesn't seem fitting. Also, $\Gamma(a) = (a-1)!$ if $a$ is a positive integer. For a gamma distribution, $a$ does not have to be a positive integer.

Comment: @Clarinetist: I was probably edited and hope now is correct.

Comment: @probablyme: Thank you very much,it sure is more complicated than I had in mind. I have only learned elementary probability and did not know these details about the formula. My friend who discussed with me this exercise majors in math. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Sure thing.${}$

Answer (score 0):

I thought that it would be instructive to present a very efficient approach that relies on the well-known relationship between the Beta function and the Gamma function

$$B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

where

$$B(x,y)=\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1}\,dt$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\Gamma(x)&=\int_0^\infty t^{x-1}e^{-t}\,dt\\\\
&=(x-1)!
\end{align}$$

Here, the integral of interest is

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^t(1-x)^{s-t}\,dx&=B(t+1,s-t+1)\\\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(t+1)\Gamma(s-t+1)}{\Gamma(s+2)}\\\\
&=\frac{t!(s-t)!}{(s+1)!}
\end{align}$$

and we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. - Mark

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), if $s-t,t$ are nonnegative integers, then notice that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1x^t(1-x)^{s-t}dx&=\frac{\Gamma(t+1)\Gamma(s-t+1)}{\Gamma(t+1+(s-t+1))}\\
&\qquad\cdot\int_0^1\frac{\Gamma(t+1+(s-t+1))}{\Gamma(t+1)\Gamma(s-t+1)}x^{(t+1)-1}(1-x)^{(s-t+1)-1}\,dx\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(t+1)\Gamma(s-t+1)}{\Gamma(s+2)}\cdot 1\\
&=\frac{t!(s-t+1)!}{(s+1)!}
\end{align*}
where the second integrand is the density of a Beta distribution.